# Decrypting an Affine Cipher $ e(m)=am+b\pmod{27}$ knowing $e(8)\equiv 14$ and $e(26)\equiv 5$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, cryptography

I began by setting up a system of linear equations:
$$14\equiv 8a+b \pmod{27}$$
$$5\equiv 26a+b\pmod{27}$$
and then subtracted them to get: $9\equiv 9a \pmod{27}$. I know $9$ doesn't have a multiplicative inverse modulo $27$ but $a=1$ would solve this. I'm afraid I must be making some mistake somewhere, however, as solving this all the way through gives me $b=6$ and then translating the message doesn't quite make sense.

Comment: You missed several solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$9a\equiv 9 \mod{27}$$
$$a \equiv1 \mod3$$
$$\therefore a=1+3k$$
$$b\equiv14-8a \mod{27}$$
$$b=14-8(1+3k)+27m$$
$$\therefore b=6-24k+27m$$
Where $k,m\in\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: So $(a,b)\in \{(1,6),(4,9),(7,12),(10,15),(13,18),(16,21),(19,24),(22,0),(25,3)\}$. Only the ones with invertible $a$, namely $a=1,7,19,25$ warrant further investigation. The others would be uninvertible.

Comment: They are all invertible mod 27 since its only prime divisor is 3 right?

Comment: @josephF yes, sorry, I switched to modulo $26$ in my head again (which is also done sometimes in some texts).

Answer (score 1):

$9\equiv 9a \ \pmod{27} \Rightarrow 9(1-a)\equiv 0\ \pmod{27} \Rightarrow 1-a\equiv 0  \pmod{3} \Rightarrow a=1+3k,\ k\in\mathbb{Z}$

Comment: okay so $a=1,4,7,10,13,16,19,22$ or $25$?

Comment: No, I never said that.  I was talking about the answer, not your comment.  Whether anyone writes $=$ or $\equiv$ hardly matters as long as the context is clear.

Comment: @Randall  You're right! My mistake, I'll try to fix it

Comment: Yes, that's correct now.  I removed my downvote.

Comment: Use `\pmod{27}` for $\pmod{27}$ ("parenthesized mod" I suppose) for nicer results.